# android don't connect to the internet

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm developing an android app, my first one and the first time I work with network stuff.

In java my code works properly, and in android I have included the `uses permission network` in the manifest but it still not work I do not know why.

My code in android is

```
ArrayList<Pair<String,String>> parameters = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
Pair<String,String> value = new Pair<String, String>("name",cadena);
parameters.add(value);
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.43:8084/DnDServer/addGame"+ Utilidades.getParameter(parameters));
mostrarError(Utilidades.getParameter(parameters));
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.connect();
mostrarError(con.getResponseCode() + "");
```

`getParameters()` returns a string like `?param1=value1&param2=value2`....

and in the android manifest i have included

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">
```

Comment: and i forgot to say thar mostrarError shows a ToastMessage. Thank you for your time and answers

Comment: Are you getting any error/logcat messages?

Comment: In which class is this network code?

Comment: http://pastie.org/9136555 The logcat

Comment: The code is in the OnClickListener, i submit you the full activity code http://pastie.org/9136562

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're performing this operation in the main UI, which is forbidden in Android because it would block the thread until it was processed, resulting probably in an Application Not Responding.

Move the network operation into an `AsyncTask`. Put the code in the `doInBackground()` method, as when it will be run, it will automatically create another thread and perform the network operation there.

Comment: Thanks, that helped, the problem was i was trying to acces in the ui, now it works, sorry for comment late